# Eclipse: Show inline javascript in Outline

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-neon

In Eclipse PDT, the outline for a PHP file has a *PHP* view and an *HTML* view. When a JavaScript file is open, its functions, vars, etc. will show up in its outline.  I'm currently using Neon.1. Although it has been a while, I'm certain in some early incarnation of Eclipse PDT I could see inline JavaScript entities by expanding the appropriate `<script>` tag in the HTML outline, but this is no longer the case.

Is there a way, when editing non-js-extension files, to either:
 add a *JavaScript* context to the outline (preferable)
or
 to at least access JavsaScript entries in the outline via the *HTML* view as I could in the past?

Eclipse version info:
Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200

Comment: Still an issue in 
Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

Comment: Same with Oxygen :(

Comment: In the end, I ditched Eclipse and switched to PHPStorm, which can handle outlining JS in mixed language files, and so, so much more.